# Keras - Stationary result using model.fit()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm implementing this simple neural network, with these inputs data:

```
x_train = np.asarray(x_train)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
x_test = np.asarray(x_test)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
```

After have defined the network's structure:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=5, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
```

I run this to train and evaluate the NN:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

and I always get the same result from model.fit( ... ) :
 *32/143 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s*.
 It seems that doesn't work at all, despite I obtain consistent results on training and validation. How does I have to interpreter this stationary result about *model. fit* output?

Comment: Sorry but the question makes no sense, I don't see what stationary result you are talking about. Can you please edit and explain?

Comment: I'm sorry, but 32/143 is not referred to the  patterns right classified (32) on the test set by the classifier? I get always the same result, despite I have a good accuracy and a small loss on training and validation.

Comment: No, that is current batch samples / total train samples, and you will see that it always goes from zero to 143 as one epoch is completed.

Comment: How could I  plot together  training, validation and test accuracy?

Comment: Could you provide us with more details about your data (size of x, etc.) - and about your loss?

Comment: @Simone That is a different question and I think it has already been answered here.